# Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard intermitently becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have a very simple Domain with a primary Domain controller, Dell PET320 and a bu dc, same model, different options. At no particular time the PDC becomes extremely sluggish, we first notice it when users are working in an access program with a SQL backend, their queries just begin to hang. The problem has only occurred about 5 times since last August but when it happens it simply takes all the users down as they are unable to function. here might be a hint, a warm reboot will NOT clear the problem, a shutdown, then restart will clear the issue. When this is happening the resource monitor looks great, CPU, Disk, Network, Memory, all look fine. The event viewer looks fantastic, literally only 1 error in app log (proof of purchase error, known Dell issue) and 1 error in the sys log about an ipmi device driver, these both repeat all the time so it is doubtful they have anything to do with it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to capture what is going on at the time of this unresponsiveness?

Comment: So you're running an LOB application that uses SQL on your Domain Controller?

Comment: yes, it is a small database and only running sql express

Comment: Get your DC off the same physical server running SQL Server; that's just not a good idea regardless... If SQL Server start getting beat up, the, your mechanism authenticating everyone, etc. hangs.... Not good, gotta make better decisions than this man... Look into `SP_WHOISACTIVE` for SQL Server and start capturing what's occurring at the SQL Server level when the issue occurs, I would never put SQL Server on a DC though --  sounds like time to consider a change.